# How to create time bins in R and group data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data.table, tidyr

I have data that looks like this:

```
trial   event   time_start  time_end    time_duration   region
1         A       36403      36504        101           none
1         B       36506      36516        10            none
1         A       36518      36700        182           top
1         B       36702      36708        6             none
1         A       36710      37054        344           top
1         B       37056      37088        32            none
1         A       37090      37640        550           right
1         B       37642      37678        36            none
1         A       37680      37812        132           left
2         A       41278      41318        40            top
2         B       41320      41336        16            none
2         A       41338      41490        152           top
2         B       41492      41498        6             none
2         A       41500      41994        494           top
2         B       41996      42032        36            none
2         A       42034      42492        458           left
```

For each trial, I want to group the data into 4 equal time bins (the total time varies for each trial). So I imagine I would need to: (1) group the data by trials, (2) add a column for the cumulative time duration for each trial, (3) divide the total time for each trial by 4 and accordingly assign each row to a time bin. This is what I'd like to get it to:

```
trial   event   time_start  time_end  time_duration  region cumtime bin
1         A       36403      36504        101         none    101    1
1         B       36506      36516        10          none    111    1
1         A       36518      36700        182         top     293    1
1         B       36702      36708        6           none    299    1
1         A       36710      37054        344         top     643    2
1         B       37056      37088        32          none    675    2
1         A       37090      37640        550         right   1225   4
1         B       37642      37678        36          none    1261   4
1         A       37680      37812        132         left    1393   4
2         A       41278      41318        40          top     40     1
2         B       41320      41336        16          none    56     1
2         A       41338      41490        152         top     208    1
2         B       41492      41498        6           none    214    1
2         A       41500      41994        494         top     708    3
2         B       41996      42032        36          none    744    3
2         A       42034      42492        458         left    1202   4
```

From the data above, I would then need to calculate the following for every bin in each trial: (1) In each time bin, the number of rows where the event is A, (2) In each time bin, the number of rows where the event is A and the region is right. This is what I am trying to get my final table to look like:

```
trial   bin totalevent_A  totalevent_A_right
1        1       2             0
1        2       1             0
1        3       0             0
1        4       2             1
2        1       2             0
2        2       0             0
2        3       1             0
2        4       1             0
```

I am not sure how to group the data by trials firstly and then divide the total Time for each trial into 4 equal time bins and assign each event to it (the complete dataset has 1000+ trials). Any suggestions/ alternate approaches would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This routine can be implemented with {dplyr} `group_by` `mutate` and `summarize`. I split it up into two result objects `res1` and `res2`

```r
dat <- read.table(text="trial   event   time_start  time_end    time_duration   region
1         A       36403      36504        101           none
1         B       36506      36516        10            none
1         A       36518      36700        182           top
1         B       36702      36708        6             none
1         A       36710      37054        344           top
1         B       37056      37088        32            none
1         A       37090      37640        550           right
1         B       37642      37678        36            none
1         A       37680      37812        132           left
2         A       41278      41318        40            top
2         B       41320      41336        16            none
2         A       41338      41490        152           top
2         B       41492      41498        6             none
2         A       41500      41994        494           top
2         B       41996      42032        36            none
2         A       42034      42492        458           left", header=TRUE)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

res1 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(duration = time_end - time_start,
         total_duration = sum(duration),
         cml_duration = cumsum(duration),
         fractime = cml_duration / total_duration,
         bin = floor(fractime / 0.25 + 0.99)) 
                                         # 0.99 < 1 : fudge factor for group 1:4 not 0:4 or 1:5
res2 <- res1 %>% 
  group_by(trial, bin) %>%
  summarize(total_event_a = sum(event == "A"), total_event_a_right = sum(event == "A" & region == "right"))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'trial' (override with `.groups` argument)

res2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   trial [2]
#>   trial   bin total_event_a total_event_a_right
#>   <int> <dbl>         <int>               <int>
#> 1     1     1             2                   0
#> 2     1     2             1                   0
#> 3     1     4             2                   1
#> 4     2     1             2                   0
#> 5     2     3             1                   0
#> 6     2     4             1                   0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Note that the exact output you wanted can be achieved by using `factor(..., levels=1:4)` when you `mutate` to create `bin`, and then the `res2` `group_by(trial, bin)` statement needs `.drop = FALSE`